# Delphi - Variants.pas unit is out of date

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

After installing Delphi RAD Studio XE on a new computer (Win 10 Pro), I can't compile existing project:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Variants.pas(1064): E2158 Variants unit out of date or corrupted: missing '@VarFromInt'.

The `Variants.pas` unit is exactly the same as before.

Comment: That looks like you are including Variants.pas in your project, perhaps a copied version. I'm surprised that you say "Variants.pas is exactly the same as before" which suggests that you perhaps have a modified version. I think there is more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: No, I only compare both units : this originally installed on new computer with that on the old one.

Comment: Then your old project probably has some hard-coded dependencies to an old version of Variants.pas (or to some runtime directory). Just close the IDE, delete the .dproj file and open the .dpr file. A new dproj will be created with the proper library settings for XE. Such things can happen when you open an old project. Be sure to copy the directory with the project to a new location first. Do not mix them.

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't help.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: The problem is in procedure VarCopyByRef in Variants.pas

Comment: You have to ask yourself why you are compiling an RTL unit. Why are you doing that? Normal usage is that you use the pre-compiled dcu files that are shipped with the product. Can you explain this?

Comment: I see that our anonymous upvoters are out in force ......

Answer (score -3):

Problem solved, invalid paths in Tools\Options\Library paths:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\source\rtl\sys

Comment: Rather than write an answer, based on information that we don't have, the best bet is to remove this question and answer which won't be useful to any other visitor. Or, if you want to keep it, edit the question so that the answer can be determined from information in the question